# Los modales de bootstrap no se muestran en mi div que carga todo mi contenido con ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax, bootstrap

Tengo un index con una navegación hecha con AJAX y así cargar todos las demás páginas dentro del `div` que tiene el index.php, para que el navegador no se recargue.

Mi problema es cuando en ese `div` quiero cargar un CRUD que hace uso de los modales de Bootstrap, ya que al abrirlos a través de un botón aparecen pero no se mantiene en la pantalla, es decir, aparece y se borra muy rápido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como se ve el index. En la opción del menú CRUD, ahí se ejecuta esta función en AJAX:

```
function crud(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "php/crud.php",//valor obligatorio para solicitar el doc que se quiere cargar
        dataType : "text",
        success : function(data) {
            $("#container").html(data);//Id del contenedor para mostrar el archivo
        }
    });
}
```

En el HTML está la función AJAX que ejecuto al darle clic:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al dar click en el botón verde se debe desplegar el modal dentro del `div` con el ID container pero solo aparece y se desvanece muy rápido. No sé qué puedo hacer para que funcione.

Éste es el código:

```
<h1>Este es la pagina principal</h1>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="crud();">CRUD</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Cargar contenido yo soy el index</h3>
    <div id="container">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor coloca el código que estás usando y revisa la redacción de tu pregunta.

Comment: Es todo el codigo, en el menu nada mas esta una opcion que ejecuta la funcion crud(); <li><a href="#" onclick="crud();">CRUD</a></li> Y luego en el div que esta en el archivo index.php carga el contenido del crud.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que ocurre aquí es que cuando inyectas el html que te retorna el ajax este tiene configuradas las clases de modal de bootstrap por lo tanto se inyecta y bootstrap js te lo oculta, lo que debes hacer es abrir el modal luego de la inyección: de esta manera:

```
function crud(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "php/crud.php",//valor obligatorio para solicitar el doc que se quiere cargar
        dataType : "text",
        success : function(data) {
            $("#container").html(data);//Id del contenedor para mostrar el archivo
            $("#TuModalID").modal('show'); //Esto abrirá el modal que inyectaste
        }});
}
```

Espero que te funcione!

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por las aportación. La verdad es que tenia un problemas con las CDN el orden no era el correcto. Gracias